# How do I get rid of mold on roughcast?

Tags: walls, mold, humidity

I've got mold on my living room's wall under my window :

[image]

This part of the wall used to be behind some furniture, so I believe the mold was caused by lack of ventilation (we are on the 2nd floor and it is the only place we have mold).

How do I get rid of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vinegar is the best option to remove the mold. The vinegar will penetrate the porous surface and remove the underlying membrane as well as the mold growth on the surface. Spray the vinegar on the surface and let it sit for an hour, then spray again and wipe off. Bleach is only good for removing mold on the surface, it doesn't penetrate the surface to kill the roots.

Comment: I've tried your solution, but the wall is getting smoother, like it's dissolving ? Is it normal ?

Comment: More than likely, it's a result of the moisture that's been there for awhile.  you might have to repaint/touch up that section after the wall dries. Vinegar doesn't dissolve paint all by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Bleach works very well on any surface,for outside, I dilute it 50 %. For interior rough surface I would try rubber gloves to hold a cleaning rag wet with 50 % bleach , it will take a couple minutes to work . Hold a second dry rag below to catch drips , any drip will likely change color of fabrics, etc. Outside I do not rinse but for inside , follow up with a clean damp cloth. I have a very humid aquarium room and mold is a general problem on walls and ceiling .

Answer (score 0):

For these, I am using a [bleaching spray from the local supermarket](https://www.coop.ch/de/haushalt-tier/reinigung-putzen/badezimmer/badreiniger/cillit-bang-badreiniger-schmutz-schimmel/p/3896401).

As per the (german, translated by me) description it cosists of

- 2,8g/100g sodium hypochlorite
- less than 5% bleach on the basis of chlorine
- anionic surfactant and non-ionic surfactant and
- Perfume

What's especially good, when applying from a short distance, it creates a foam which can stay on for a while.

Wipe clean with a cloth. You need not use much force, so the wall coverage should stay on.

I have used this today to get rid of a patch of mold exactly like the one you show in the picture.